# Oracle APEX - How to display image on left side of screen?

Tags: oracle-apex

Running Oracle Application Express version 5.0.  I have a region, which has 3 graphics.  They are three separate files, all of type DISPLAY_IMAGE.  While they display properly (one on top of the other), their location is wrong.  The top image is a logo, and I want it at the far left of the screen.   Right now, they all come in around 40% of the screen, then display one above the other.  How do I set an image to display immediate at the left border?  I have tried setting setting column/column span, I have tried various HTML tags, etc, but I am new to Oracle APEX, and something this simple is causing me challenges...  What do I set, and what field do I place that setting in?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in oracle apex 5.0 there is a new feature called `Page Designer` which is used for managing layout of page in gui

you can check following doc

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/overview/apex-50-pd-otn-2030491.pdf

or make a search in google for usage videos or documents